# How to specify that I can accept all media types in the Accept header?

Tags: http, http-headers, http-accept-header

I want to send an HTTP request and I want to specify that I can accept all media types in the **Accept** header, is the following correct:

```
Accept: */*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Take a look at [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2)

> The asterisk `*` character is used to group media types into ranges,
> with `*/*` indicating **all media types**